# How to do http requests periodically correctly?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make requests in the background every 30 seconds and foreground every 5 seconds, how to use `Stream` in this case?

here is my code:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      // background proccess off
      setPost(30);
    } else {
      // background proccess on
      setPost(5);
    }
  }

  Stream<int> setPost(int seconds) async* {
    yield* Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: seconds), (int i) {
      post();
      return i;
    });
  }

  void post() async {
    try {
      var header = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      };
      var response = await http.post(url, headers: header);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.body);
      } else {
        print(response.body);
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      print('not connected');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Timer.pediodic`:

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  Timer timer;
  bool waitingForResponse = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this); // Adding an observer
    setTimer(false);  // Setting a timer on init
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer?.cancel();  // Cancelling a timer on dispose
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this); // Removing an observer
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    setTimer(state != AppLifecycleState.resumed);
  }

  void setTimer(bool isBackground) {
    int delaySeconds = isBackground ? 5 : 3;

    // Cancelling previous timer, if there was one, and creating a new one
    timer?.cancel();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: delaySeconds), (t) async {
      // Not sending a request, if waiting for response
      if (!waitingForResponse) {
        waitingForResponse = true;
        await post();
        waitingForResponse = false;
      }
    });
  }

  // Async method returns Future<> object
  Future<void> post() async {
    ...
  }

  ...
```